# Does sslstrip have to do something with Bettercap's certificate?

Tags: tls, http, man-in-the-middle, sslstrip, bettercap

I am trying to perform a MITM attack using bettercap against a website that doesn't have the HSTS security policy implemented at all.

When I try the following command: `bettercap -T AddressIpoftheTarget -X --proxy --https-proxy`, it works fine. Bettercap succeeds in injecting his own self-signed certificate to the web browser. The browser shows the "Not Secure" warning, and lets me accept the invalid certificate by proceeding to the website in an unsecure way.

When I try this command: `bettercap -T AddressIpoftheTarget -X --https-proxy` it doesn't work. I don't understand why the `--proxy` is needed. Is it because it enables the `sslstrip`? How does `sslstrip` contribute in all of this during this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; the `--proxy` argument enables `sslstrip`. The `sslstrip` module in Bettercap re-writes any `https://` links (and also I think by default adds an extra character to the hostname to defeat HSTS policy if it enabled). As to why the `--proxy` switch is needed - if there is no HSTS, then the initial page will be served over HTTP.